# Можно ли использовать два callback_data в aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram, callback

Хотела бы уточнить, есть ли возможность сделать чтобы когда переходишь во втором меню по любой из кнопок, далее выводится третье меню и далее планируется, чтобы исходя из того какая кнопка была нажата во втором меню, выводился результат. Можно ли как-то считывать 2 callback_Data(2-е меню(1, 2, 3) и 3-е меню) и исходя из этого выводить следующее меню/ответ?

```html
#Второе меню
inline_1 = InlineKeyboardButton('1', callback_data='1')
inline_2 = InlineKeyboardButton('2', callback_data='2')
inline_3 = InlineKeyboardButton('3', callback_data='3')
inline_second_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(inline_1, inline_2, inline_3)

#Третье меню
inline_min_max = InlineKeyboardButton('Мин/Мах', callback_data='min-max')
inline_all = IlineKeyboardButton('Все', callback_data='all')
inline_third_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(inline_min_max,inline_all)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == ['1', '2', '3'])
async def test(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await callback_query.message.edit_text(text='Выберите',reply_markup=inline_third_menu)
```